# Why doesn't my 404 error display unless I use res.end()?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node, and I have this code

```
var http = require('http');
// var data = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  if (req.url === '/') {

    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/html"});
    var html = require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html');
    html.on('data', function (chunk) {
      res.write(chunk);
    })
  }
  else if (req.url === '/api') {

    var obj = {
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Smith'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "application/json"});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
  else {

    res.writeHead(404, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
    res.write("Error 404: Page not found.");
    res.end();
  }


}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server listening on port 1337');
```

For some reason, 404 response will not display unless I use res.end(), even though the other two responses display fine without res.end(). Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Mozilla and chrome are behaving differently. I couldnt find definite answer although. But changing `content-type` to `application/json` for `404` condition chrome is displaying the message.